Inconsistent formula between DDPM and DDIM
I'm reading paper DDIM (Denoising Diffusion Implicit Models). The author mentioned an equation for forward process .i.e $q(x_t|x_{t-1})$ as :

DDPM  are learned with a fixed (rather than trainable) inference procedure inference procedure $q(x_{1:T}|x_{0})$, and latent variables relatively high dimensional. For example, Ho et al. (2020) considered the following Markov chain with Gaussian transitions parameterized by a decreasing sequence $\alpha_{1:T} \in (0,1\rbrack^T$:


$q(x_{1:T}|x_0):=\prod q(x_t|x_{t-1})$ where $q(x_t|x_{t-1}):=\mathcal{N}(\sqrt \frac{\alpha_t}{\alpha_{t-1}}\textbf{x}_{t-1}, (1 - \frac{\alpha_t}{\alpha_{t-1}}),\textbf{I}) \space (3)$

But in DDPM or some other sources like here and here:

$q(x_t|x_{t-1}):=\mathcal{N}(\textbf{x}_t,\sqrt{1-\beta_t}\textbf{x}_{t-1}, \beta_t\textbf{I})$

Where $\beta_t = 1-\alpha_{t-1}$
Although citing directly from the DDPM paper, the authors of DDIM use a completely different formula, or at least I misunderstood something. Where does the issue lie?
